# How can I reuse columns and events in Doctrine 2 Entities?

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm, observer-pattern, composition

Suppose I'm writing a blog app: My `Posts` Entity should have a `createddate`, `modifieddate`, `name`, and [`slug`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29) property (the slug would be generated when I call setName() for the Entity). I want to reuse this code, but I also want to reuse it *on-demand*. I may, for instance, have a `Log` Entity which wants to use `createddate`, but not `modifieddate` or `slug` functionality.

Class inheritance, whether via [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) (mixins) or abstract classes, seems to be an insufficient, or at least improper, approach to reusing this functionality, as it doesn't pass the *is-a* test. After all, the Entity *has-a* createddate, but isn't a createddate itself.. so we should use Composition rather than Inheritance, right?. However, [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) doesn't seem to work here, since while I want to use this functionality *on-demand*, Doctrine's use of annotation and object properties seem to make horizontal injection difficult (and expensive?) without use of [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

To show some code and simplify the question a bit: **can I at once inject the following definition and functionality into an Entity without breaking [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) or good OOP (proper use of composition / inheritance) practice?**

```
/**
 * @var DateTime $createddate
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createddate;

/**
  * @ORM\PrePersist
  */
public function createddatePrePersist() {
    $this->createddate = new \DateTime('now');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal opinion is that you're trying to find the nail for your hammer. You don't *have* to use composition, inheritance, traits, or any OOP pattern for every entity.

I tend to consider that the `creationDate` is an inherent property of my entity, and any entity that requires a creation date has this property. One may argue that's repeating myself, but in my opinion that makes the whole entity much easier to read.

Oh, and if I may, I wouldn't use an ORM-specific method, which is not part of my domain model, to initialise the creation date. This would be done in my constructor:

```php
/**
 * @var DateTime $createddate
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $createddate;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->createddate = new \DateTime();
    // ... and other business rules that need to be enforced in the constructor
}
```